# My <p> tag is taking style from another tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, tags

```
<FormWrap>  
    <FormImg img src='./img/CB.png' alt="CB" /> 
    <FormContent>                   
       <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
           {errorMessage && (<p className="errorM"> {errorMessage} </p>)}
           <FormH1>Log in to your account</FormH1>
           <FormLabel htmlFor='for'>Email</FormLabel>
           <FormInput type='text' value={email} required
            onChange={e => setemail(e.target.value)}/>
           <FormLabel htmlFor='for'>Password</FormLabel>
           <FormInput type='password' value={password} required 
            onChange={e => setpassword(e.target.value)}/>
           <FormButton type='submit'>Sign in</FormButton>
     <Navtext>
        <NavtextLink to="/Register">Register</NavtextLink>
     </Navtext>

    </Form> 
                        
                         
      </FormContent>
</FormWrap>
```

```
export const errorM = styled.p`
    width:1000px;
    height:692px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr;
    position:relative;
    
    border-radius:10px;
    `


export const FormWrap = styled.div`
    width:800px;
    height:692px;
    background:white;
    color:yellow;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr;
    position:relative;
    
    border-radius:10px;


    @media screen and (max-width: 980px){
        height:95%;
        padding:50px;


    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 720px){
        height:90%;
        padding-left:95px;
    }
`
```

The thing is that errorM is taking the style from FormWrap even through the one is

and the other is <div.I tried to make inline style but then only that I managed to change was the cooler of the texts tried to change the fond but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example, the `<p>` has the className "errorM".
And in your second code example, you have created a styled component called "errorM".

When you create a styled component the variable should start with a capital letter, for example, `ErrorM`.

There are two ways to add the style to `<p>` tag.

1. Applying style to the className.
   Change `export const errorM = styled.p` to `.errorM { ... }`.
2. Using the styled component instead of adding className to `<p>`.
   Change `<p className="errorM">{errorMessage}</p>` to `<ErrorM>{errorMessage}</ErrorM>`

Answer (score 0):

use id to specify particular paragraph

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #one{
  color:blue;
  }
  </style>  
  <title>Browser</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Write, edit and run HTML, CSS and JavaScript code online.</h1>
<p id="one">
This is paragraph
</p>

</body>

</html>
```